# Обращение к элементам списка

Tags: java, arraylist

Доброго времени суток. Есть класс с 2-мя полями типа String. На основе этого класса создан список (ArrayList). Как обращаться к элементам этого списка?

Ответ: list.get(0).name,    где name поле из класса.

Comment: arrayList по сути является массивом. значит все элементы его индексированы, следловательно любой из них можно получить по этому индексу черезе гет. если нужны все - пройдитесь циклом, либо с помощью streaм api. Но мой вам совет - уделите много времени и хорошенько изучите коллекции. без этого писать на java просто нереально. это ультимативная вещь

Comment: list.get(0); так будет выводить хэш код.

Comment: нкт, так быудет выводить первый элемнт коллекции, а не хеш код

Comment: если у вас хеш-код выходит, то показывайте код. но дело точно не в вызове гет у коллекции

Comment: хотя, я кажется понял... вы создали ArrayList нетипизированный и у вас возвращается не экземпляр класса, а Object. создайте ArrayList <ИмяВашегоКласса>list = new ArrayList<>(); тогда list.get(0); вернет вам экземпляр типа вашего класса, в котором и есть ваши 2 стринга в виде полей. как-то так...

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток!

Для того, чтобы обращаться к данным элемента списка по указанному индексу необходимо использовать метод `get(int index)`, который возвращает объект типа, указанного при объявлении списка. Далее Вам просто будет необходимо использовать полученный объект и выполнять необходимые действия.

Подробнее о методе можно узнать в документации к платформе: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-

Comment: Понял спасибо. Чуток подзабыл.